# How can i move a frame with buttons in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, int

I made a button that plus the x axis with 50 if i press it.If i press the button tho it doesn't move,yes it changes the value but doesn't move. I tried a while loop but it crashed the program.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include your code in the question so users can identify any problems with your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

In general we use `pack` and `grid` geometry managers to handle widget placement in Tk. However, if you *want* to explicitly control the placement then you can use `place` which allows you to specify the location in either pixel or relative coordinates.

Here is an example of a frame with a button inside that moves when you click the button. Note that the button is positioned relative to its parent container so moves with the frame.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class App(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super(App, self).__init__(master=master, **kwargs)
        master.wm_geometry('640x480')
        self.frame = f = tk.Frame(self, width=200, height=80, relief=tk.SUNKEN, borderwidth=2)
        b = ttk.Button(f, text="Move", command=self.move_frame)
        b.place(x=2, y=2)
        f.place(x=2, y=2)
        self.place(relheight=1.0, relwidth=1.0)

    def move_frame(self):
        x = self.frame.winfo_x()
        x = x + 10
        self.frame.place(x=x)

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Yes i know how to.pack or .grid but the only problem is when i plus the x-axis or y-axis it does not move at all